# How to load the data when the page first load When I use vue js?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

This is my code:

```
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="task in tasks">@{{task.body}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/vue/1.0.24/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:"#app",
        data:{
            tasks:[
                {body:'go to  home',complete:true},
                {body:'watch tv',complete:true},
                {body:'go to bed',complete:true},
            ]
        }
    });
</script>
```

How I should do load the data 'tasks' from database when the page first load,I use php,vue js!!!

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/#ready

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Vue api documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/). It's full of useful information: from the basics to the nitty-gritty. It's even searchable!

Specifically, familiarize yourself with the [lifecycle](http://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) of Vue, and how to hook into it.

You're probably interested in either the [ready](http://vuejs.org/api/#ready) or [created](http://vuejs.org/api/#created) lifecycle hook.

In particular, anything in the `created` hook will be run before the Vue element is is compiled. So you may want to place your logic there.

```
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
        tasks:[
            {body:'go to  home',complete:true},
            {body:'watch tv',complete:true},
            {body:'go to bed',complete:true},
        ]
    },

    created: function() {
        /** Load task from database here **/
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on asemahle's answer, you'd typically use a JSON endpoint on the server-side to deliver data for the vue.js data model. If you were using jQuery, for example, it'd look something like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        tasks: []
    },

    created: function() {
        var that = this;
        $.getJSON('/task-list', function(response) {
            that.tasks = response;
        });
    }
```

});